# sonar rule "possible null pointer exception"

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm finding a problem in my Sonar I don't know how to solve.

The error I have is:

```
Possible null pointer dereference in mypackage.myMethod(String) due to return value of called method
```

At the very begining it was:

```
 response.getBody().getData();
```

So what I did was:

```
return (response != null && response.getBody() != null) ? response.getBody().getData() : null;
```

But the error is still there.

Am I missunderstanding the error?? How can I solve?

Comment: Each time you invoke a method, you might get back a different result. Store `response.getBody()` in a variable.

Comment: Your fix now returns `null` in some possible cases (I guess), maybe you created just another *Possible null pointer dereference in mypackage.myMethod(String) due to* **return value of called method**. The error message is right, I think. `… ? response.getBody().getData() : null;` is what I mean. You could define some default response data (initialized) and return that if the response you get is `null`.

Comment: what is the type of response ?

Comment: Show more code.

Comment: Are you expecting `response` or `response.getBody()` to return null during normal operation of your application?  If not, you should treat such conditions as errors by throwing exceptions, rather than just returning null to indicate an error.

Comment: @AndyTurner your solution works perfect! if you want, include as answer to mark it as solution. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you invoke a method, you might get back a different result. You may know that you will get the same result back each time, but Sonarqube doesn't.

Assign `response.getBody()` to a variable so you don't have to call it again:

```
if (response != null) {
  var body = response.getBody();
  if (body != null) {
    return body.getData();
  }
}
return null;
```

You can do it with Optional, alternatively:

```
return Optional.ofNullable(response).map(ResponseType::getBody).map(BodyType::getData).orElse(null);
```